# Console output from parallel jobs getting skewed in tcsh

Tags: linux, console, makefile, tcsh

I have a makefile which I call with -j switch to enable parallel executions. Each of the target prints out a little "Running this target" message before the actual job runs. Most of the times the console output looks good. I see the prints in correct order and aligned left of the console, like so:

```
Running target1
Running target2
Running target3
```

But when one or more of the targets fail, the screen output is skewed/offset by whitespaces, like so:

```
Running target1
        Running target2
                Running target3
                        make: *** [target3] Error
```

Once the skewing starts, every next print is skewed regardless of whether the target succeeds or fails.

This is really annoying especially because I don't understand the reason. Why does this skewing happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: You are using `tcsh` as your main shell or as the shell for the recipes in the makefile?

Comment: I'm guessing this is just because the different processes don't lock the stdout/stderr and write to them at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

As Carpetsmoker pointed out, the skewing is because of multiple processes writing to stderr/stdout at the same time.

make (version 4.0 or higher I guess) provides an option to sync output (--output-sync or -O) with varying levels of granularity. This option does exactly what I want!

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html